# Extraer en java elementos con un patrón (expresiones regulares)

Tags: java, regex

Debo recoger con un BufferedReader un archivo .txt con varias líneas de texto.

El caso es que debo filtrar mediante pattern / matcher las lineas que siguen el patrón:

```
elemento1,elemento2,elemento3,elemento4
```

He leído que se hace con expresiones regulares pero no encuentro como crear ese patrón, desconozco esto de las expresiones regulares.

Estos elementos deben registrarse luego en un List de una clase que tiene como constructor el formato (String id, String nombre, String descripcion, double precio).
Entiendo que la expresión regular debería ser algo tipo [texto,texto,texto,numero con decimal]

¿Sabéis que tipo de expresión regular se utilizaría en algo así?

He creado esto:

```
[0-9]{1,},[a-zA-Z]{1,},[a-zA-Z0-9 ]{1,},[0-9.]+[^.]
```

Teniendo en cuenta que los elementos del .txt son así:

```
[numeros en string],[una palabra],[una frase alfanumérica],[un número decimal]
```

¿Debería valer verdad?

Comment: Hola Ruze, si cada línea tiene lo que dices, es decir: "elemento1,elemento2,elemento3,elemento4", siempre puedes cortar la línea con ".split()" y usar la coma "," como medida de corte. Desconozco si el uso de "BufferedReader" es obligatorio o no, pero en caso de que no lo sea, considera lo que te he comentado, te ahorraría quebraderos de cabeza.

Comment: Pon código para poder replicar tus resultados y hacer las correcciones necesarias. Y un ejemplo del contenido del archivo.

Comment: `1234,puerco,puercote1,99` sería un valor válido?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo le veo un error a tu expresión regular:

```
[0-9]{1,},[a-zA-Z]{1,},[a-zA-Z0-9 ]{1,},[0-9.]+[^.]
```

Debería de ser:

```
[0-9]{1,},[a-zA-Z]{1,},[a-zA-Z0-9 ]{1,},[0-9.]+[^\.]
```

Esto debido a que si no lo tomaría como cualquier caracter.

Para facilitarte la extracción usa grupos, para ello cada sección que quieres extraer la pones entre paréntesis:

```
([0-9]{1,}),([a-zA-Z]{1,}),([a-zA-Z0-9 ]{1,}),([0-9.]+)[^\.]
```

Tu matcher tiene la capacidad de extraer cada grupo uno por uno.

Lo siguiente que veo que le faltó a tu expresión regular es delimitadores... `^` y `$` indican inicio de línea y fin de línea respectivamente.

```
^([0-9]{1,}),([a-zA-Z]{1,}),([a-zA-Z0-9 ]{1,}),([0-9.]+)[^\.]$
```

En el caso del tercer elemento/grupo debes notar que acepta espacios, tal vez esto sea intencional, pero ten en cuenta que podría ir un espacio en blanco y nada más.

Un código que te puede ayudar a probarlo sería:

```
List<String> allGroups = new ArrayList<>();
try {
   Matcher m = Pattern.compile("([0-9]{1,}),([a-zA-Z]{1,}),([a-zA-Z0-9 ]{1,}),([0-9.]+)[^\\.]").matcher("1234,puerco,puercote1,99");
   int groupsNum = m.groupCount();
   while (m.find()) {
       for (int i = 1; i <= groupsNum; i++) {
           try {
               String group = m.group(i);
               allGroups.add(group);
           } catch (IllegalStateException ise) {
               allGroups.add("No Matches");
           }
       }
   }
} catch (PatternSyntaxException pse) {
   allGroups.add(pse.getMessage());
}
```

Este código lo he generado con mi plugin para expresiones regulares [Dukescript Java Regex Tester](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/11370-dukescript-java-regex-tester) que pretende ser un entorno de desarrollo de expresiones regulares para la familia de lenguajes relacionados con Java.